# traverson.js integration into Angular2 app

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, hateoas

Has anyone successfully integrated traverson into an Angular2 app?  If so, is there a step-by-step available?

Trying to integrate traverson.js into an Angular2 app for HATEOAS traversal. Attempted pulling in traverson.js per this technique (https://medium.com/@s_eschweiler/using-external-libraries-with-angular-2-87e06db8e5d1#.9qx93kgki).

Run into dependency problems, starting with traverson's use of "require()".  typical error:

> Uncaught Error: Module name "minilog" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

Also tried using `ngUpgrade` to bring in traverson-angular (angular 1.x based module), and ran into more dependency problems...

Answer (score 1):

I managed to simply install traverson and use it in an angular service:

```
npm install traverson
```

And then, in your service:

```
// imports

const traverson = require('traverson');

@Injectable() 
export class Service { 
   public getData(): Observable<Data> {
      const promise: Promise<Counterparty> = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
         traverson 
         .from('http://my-api.com') 
         // Add your traverson options here
         .follow('link', 'other-link')
         .getResource((error, data) => { 
              if (error) { 
                reject(error); 
              } else { 
                resolve(data); 
              });
      }
      return Observable.fromPromise(promise); 
   }
}
```

The problem here is that there is no up-to date typings for traverson yet so you have an hybrid JS/TS code.

I did not manage to use observables directly that's why I pass by a promise, which is much simpler by the way.

Note that traverson uses its own http client. If you want to use the angular http client, you need to create a bridge class, that implements the following methods:

```
get(uri: string, options: any, callback: (err, response) => void);
del(uri: string, options: any, callback: (err, response) => void);
post(uri: string, options: any, callback: (err, response) => void);
put(uri: string, options: any, callback: (err, response) => void);
patch(uri: string, options: any, callback: (err, response) => void);
```

The `options` are the traverson options.

Hope this helps